# Determine P(A|(A U B))

Tags: probability, statistics

> Given, $P(A) = 0.2,  P(B) = 0.5,  P(A' \cup B') = 0.9$, find $P(A|A\cup B)$.

What I did:

$$P(A|(A \cup B)) = \frac{P(A \cap (A \cup B))}{P(A \cup B)}$$

Now I don’t understand how to proceed with this.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please learn mathjax to write math in a more readable way: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference is a quick reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't solve the whole problem, but $$A\cap(A\cup B) = A.$$ So using the definition of conditional as you did:

$$P(A|(A\cup B)) = \frac{P(A\cap(A\cup B))}{P(A\cup B)}$$$$ = \frac{P(A)}{P(A\cup   B)} = \frac{P(A)}{ 1 - P((A\cup B)') }$$

Which by de Morgan’s first law:

$$P(A|(A\cup B)) =  \frac{P(A)}{1 - P(A'\cap B')}$$

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please learn mathjax to convey your ideas in a more readable format on the site. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference